# ubuntu 12.04 booting from a thumb drive - how to reasonably safely eject the drive after boot?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb

I have a kubuntu 12.04 booting from a thumb drive, which works well, but I would like to be able to then pull out the thumb drive and hopefully not damage the file system so much that it will not boot.

There are a few scenarios I have, but basically I need to be able to boot up from the thumb drive, start a couple programs (or they may auto-start) and then pull it.

I already know the programs will continue to run / do not write any data, but I want to prevent the drive from becoming damaged and not able to boot (or prevent the system from hanging) when I remove the drive.

Possibly there is a way to boot with the drive in read only (but allow me to put it in to read-write if I need to make changes)?  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the machine comes up, you should be able to use something like

```
# Remount as read-only
mount -o remount,ro /
```

Alternatively, you can set it to read-only in the fstab and use something like

```
# Remount as read-write
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: when I run the first one, it says mount: / is busy.      The second approach almost works - however, if I set fstab to mount ro, then my X environment does not load.  In fact, I see no login prompt at all.   I was able to ssh in to it and then remount rw, but it seems like I need to let the system boot up in to X, then switch to read only if possible.

Comment: Change your /tmp to tempfs. Maybe also your /var/log - be aware that will be erased on reboot.

Comment: still no go - it's strange, it is trying - the screen goes black, but then nothing.  I am looking in the dmesg and syslog but nothing obvious yet.  I also tried startx and lightdm start and same thing - black screen.

Comment: I know it's possible, that's how a live DVD works (e.g. read only), maybe you need a writable unionfs (with tempfs).

Comment: I finally figured it out - the x environment was because of /var/lib/lightdm. mounting that as tmpfs fixed that, but then I was not able to login.   so then mounting my home directory as tmpfs fixed that and now it boots right up in to the desktop!    granted, all my home directory files are gone each time, but thats ok for my purpose.